# Why is Java/Linux appending 0xa to end of file?

Tags: java, linux

I'm writing a file using `FileOutputStream`, and I'm noticing the hex seems to include a terminating `0x0a`. Here is the output from the file:

```
0000000: d100 0b00 0000 4865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c  ......Hello worl
0000010: 6429 0043 0500 0000 7072 696e 740a       d).C....print.

(Note hex code comes from vim on Osx Yosimite x64)
```

Notice that the file ends in `0x0a`. Is this a linux thing (like some sort of EOF character) or is this java/`FileOutputStream` appending the character?

Edit: Code

```
public class FileImageOpcodeRenderer implements OpCodeRenderer, AutoCloseable {
  private final FileOutputStream stream;
  private final Iterable<OpCode> opcodes;
  private final List<Byte> data = new ArrayList<>();

  public FileImageOpcodeRenderer(Iterable<OpCode> opcodes, String path) {
    this.opcodes = opcodes;
    try {
      this.stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();

      throw new CompilerException("Unable to open output file");
    }
  }

  public void save() throws Exception {
    List<Byte> renderedContent = renderOpCodes();
    byte[] content = toArray(renderedContent);
    stream.write(content, 0, content.length);
  }

  private List<Byte> renderOpCodes() {
    for (OpCode opCode : opcodes) {
      writeInt8(null, opCode.opNumber());
      opCode.render(this);
    }

    return this.data;
  }

  private byte[] toArray(List<Byte> data) {
    byte[] content = new byte[data.size()];

    for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++) {
      content[index] = data.get(index);
    }

    return content;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeInt8(String label, int value) {
    data.add((byte)value);
  }

  @Override
  public void writeInt16(String label, int value) {
    writeInt8(null, (byte)(value & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF));
  }

  @Override
  public void writeInt32(String label, int value) {
    writeInt8(null, (byte)(value & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 16) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 24) & 0xFF));
  }

  @Override
  public void writeInt64(String label, long value) {
    writeInt8(null, (byte)(value & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 16) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 24) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 32) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 40) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 48) & 0xFF));
    writeInt8(null, (byte)((value >> 56) & 0xFF));
  }

  @Override
  public void writeString(String label, String value) {
    writeInt32(null, value.length());
    for (byte letter : value.getBytes()) {
      System.out.println((int)letter);
      writeInt8(null, letter);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    stream.close();
  }
 }
```

I'm even looking at the raw bytes in `save` and it ends with `0x74`, not `0x0a`.

Update: Moar Code:

So I just wrote this code to load the file in c++:

```
int main() {
    int fd = open("/Users/sircodesalot/Desktop/image.vbaj", O_RDONLY);

    char buffer[256] { };
    int amout = read(fd, buffer, 256);

    cout << amout << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index != 256; ++index) {
        if (index > 0 && (index % 10 == 0)) cout << endl;
        cout << hex << (int)buffer[index] << " ";
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

which outputs this:

```
29
ffffffd1 0 b 0 0 0 48 65 6c 6c 
6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 29 0 43 
5 0 0 0 70 72 69 6e 74 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
... (rest of the 256 byte buffer)
```

Look ma, no `0xa`? What's the deal with that? Maybe some linux convention?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: 0x0a is a linefeed, the line separator on Linux. What did you write exactly?

Comment: Are linefeeds always appended to the end of a file? The routine used to write 'Hello world' is the same as the one to write 'print', so why does one have a linefeed, but not the other?

Comment: linefeeds are not automatically appended to files. It would only happen if you used `println` for example.

Comment: Why don't you show the statements used to write the file?

Comment: Updated with code. Both "Hello World" and "print" use `writeString`.

Comment: Updated with more code.

Comment: @ChrisK it looks like this may not be a duplicate.

Comment: I guess your hex output shows the bytes swapped and the file actually ends with 0x0a 0x74. How did you produce the hexdump?

Comment: Ok, in that case the 0x0a is added by vim.

Comment: @Henry why would it just add extra characters?

Comment: Because vim does not like a last line that does not end with a line feed. To check, use some other program to see the contents of the file, for example `hexdump -C filename`

Answer (score -3):

The problem *probably* lies here:

```
@Override
public void writeString(String label, String value) {
  writeInt32(null, value.length());
  for (byte letter : value.getBytes()) {
      System.out.println((int)letter);
      writeInt8(null, letter);
  }
}
```

You are writing the length in characters, but then proceed to write the bytes from getBytes(). getBytes() uses the platform encoding for the String, and depending on what the encoding is getBytes() can return you about *anything*.

Try explicitly specifying the encoding e.g. `value.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));`

Edit: Also make sure the Strings you output do contain what you think they contain.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but that didn't work.

Comment: Stopped caring about anonymous downvotes on the second day on SO :)

Comment: I wrote some c code to load the file, and it seems to be ignoring the `0xa`. I wonder if terminating a file with a linefeed some sort of posix convention.

Comment: @sircodesalot Where do all the zeros at the end come from in your edit? Looks like whatever you used to generate the hex dump modified the input (assuming they are from the same file). Did you by chance load it as *text* and then switched to hex display?

Comment: I'm using a 256 byte array buffer, so the uninitialized stuff is written too.